# Stuck on the "Welcome to raspberry Pi" Screen

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I am new to raspberry pi, and am having trouble with getting my model 5 (and 4) to work. It is permanently stuck on the 'Welcome To Raspberry Pi' screen after the rainbow screen.

I have used the imager to download the recommended OS on the Imager (A port of Debian Bookworm with the Raspberry Pi Desktop 64-Bit), and am using a brand new micro sd card (Silicon Power 128GB Superior Micro SDXC UHS-I (U3), V30 4K A2, High Speed MicroSD Card), as well as the standard power raspberry pi power supply. The STAT LED is shining green (without flashing) and no other lights are on.

I am using a micro hdmi to hdmi cable and my screen is 1920x1080, but I am using a large (27in) monitor, so could that be the problem?

It would be great if anyone could give any advice on what to do to make it work from here, because nothing has been working. If you need any extra information, please tell me. I have tried using different power supplies, re-downloading the OS, using different OS versions, and different raspberry Pis (I had the exact same problem with the model 4). Is there some step I am missing or something, because I haven't even managed to start any raspberry Pis yet.

Comment: What does the diagnostics screen show when powering the Pi5 with no sd card? Specifically the display EDID recognition.

Comment: These are the power and display lines:
display: DISP0: HDMI HPD=1 EDID = ok #2  DISP1: HPD=0 EDID=none #0
power: supply: USB-C 3000mA CC1 PMIC: reset normal 0x0 usb_over_current=0
@CoderMike

Comment: EDID = ok looks good. Have you got another sd card? I tend to use Sandisk 32GB cards. What is the specification of your power supply?

Comment: Power output: 5.1V 3A 15.3W (Standard Raspberry Pi )
I do have a sandisk 16gb card, but I don't think it worked on that either, I'll try again

Comment: @CoderMike
I tried the 16GB card and it worked!!!
Thank you so much for the help, I am infinitely grateful having been stuck on the problem for so long.